# Grade 12 Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm struggling with the following:

> Describe a function that has
>
> a. a domain of $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 2 \leq x \leq 10\}$, and
>
> b. a range of $\{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid 5 \leq y \leq 10\}$.
>
> Your function does not need to be a polynomial or rational function, and it can be described algebraically, as a graph, or in another form.

It's a question from a self-directed online grade 12 functions course I'm doing. I understand that the domain and range are restricted by the given parameters, but how do I CREATE the function to fit within them? I don't feel the unit focused on it from this perspective.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to draw a solution, ignoring what the actual functional form of your solution is.  What are obvious choices for endpoints of your graph (though there are many), then what can it do in between?  You don't need to, but try to stick with functions that don't have a break or jump in them (these are called continuous).  You should find that you can draw many, and there should be at least one where it is very easy to then write down the resulting equation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Given your advice I would just want to draw a linear function going up vertically from (2,5) - (10,10) - but without setting restrictions, this function and all continuous functions (as far as I understand) go well beyond the required limited domain and range. Are they asking me to restrict the function, do you think?

Comment: While most functions defined on this domain are also defined on a larger domain (for example all real numbers) all you are being asked to do here is consider functions that are defined between 2 and 10 and stay between 5 and 10. I'd say the second is the bigger restriction.  As you noted, a linear function is easiest to describe but you could consider functions that "wiggle" such as a higher order polynomial.  The answers below adequately cover this as well, though one interprets the original points (a) and (b) as two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is testing your understanding of function notation.

The first question asks for a function with a domain of $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 2 \le x \le 10 \}.$ Here's an example: let $f : [2,10] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2.$ To be slightly more verbose: let $f$ be the function defined by $f(x) = x^2$ for every $x \in [2,10]$ and undefined everywhere else. There is no significance to my choice of $x^2$, I could have just as easily chosen $1$, $x$, $e^x$, $\sin x$, or any other function of $x$. The construction of a function with a given domain is always somewhat arbitrary. After all, when we define any function, we are required to specify what its domain is.

The second question asks for a function with a range of $\{ y \in \mathbb{R} : 5 \le y \le 10 \}.$ Here's an example: let $f(x) = 2.5\sin x + 7.5$. Implicity, the domain of $f$ is the real numbers. However, the form of the function forces our range to be restricted to $[5,10]$. Another, more explicit example: let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = 5x + 5$. This function has a codomain of $\mathbb{R}$. But, in fact, the range (which is the image of the function under the domain) is $[5,10]$. To see this, confirm that $5x + 5$ is an increasing function, $f(0) = 5$, and $f(1) = 10$. In general, if we want to construct a function with a range of $[a,b]$ (with $a < b$), we simply define $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = (b - a)x + a$. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Ian, that was very helpful and connected some points with info I don't recall reading in my course.

Comment: @DanMurray Remember to accept answers (click the check mark next to an answer) that you like the most.

Answer (score 3):

Draw the lines $x=2$ and $x=10$, then the lines $y=5$ and $y=10$. Draw any random curve that satisfies the vertical line test in the rectangle that is formed, including the boundaries. Then you have completed the exercise.

For your comment, what you could do is define a function $f(x)$ piecewise such that it is equal to the line connecting $(2,5)$ and $(10,10)$ in the requested domain but is nonexistent elsewhere.